# JavaScript try/catch and ajax reporting

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

There's something I'd like to do with my JavaScript deployments, and I'm looking for a really slick way to do it.

I'd like to run a `try/catch` on my code, which shouldn't be super impressive or complicated, but here's what I would like to do when I have a failure: **let the dev team know,** rather than waiting for that one-off customer that cares enough to write an email on the chance he notices something that breaks.

My initial thought was to write a support submission object which I could code to take any random data (i.e., `report.submit(issue_data);`), and create an ajax call to my server that silently adds the data to an inbox or a database or *whatever*.

I thought I could do it something like:

```
try {
    some_code();
} catch(e) {
    do_instead(); 
    report.submit(issue_data);
    report.update(); //Could perhaps show the users a history of errors
}
```

But, I'd like to see if there's a better solution...better as in solving an unseen flaw here, doing things more seamlessly, advice on how to deal with failures of the submission system, perhaps using the prototype in some exciting way, etc.

Also, my simple solution here has a lot of limitations that could make the whole thing semi-useless, such as not being able to indicate the specific part of the code that failed, line numbers, conditions to create failure, browser version, etc.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.  I would use something like CouchDB because it can be accessed from the client (no server code required).

Comment: I've ninja-edited some limitations we'd have with my solution into it since first posting.

Comment: You could make a function that handles the call for you. In your code, you could call it whenever something bad happens.  This way you can give more detailed information.  Or just put all of that into your exception and post with JSON.stringify.

Comment: Be sure to only try-catch the code that is not expected to fail; you don't want your dev team to be getting a boatload of emails just because a user has decided to enforce stricter limits on what js can do within their browser. Your well-intentioned email could easily become a liability if it were wrapping code that a user might not want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem with these is that you have to be able to get those reports back.  What we've done on my project is to have a logger REST resource and use [log4javascript's](http://log4javascript.org/index.html) `AjaxAppender`.

Answer (score 1):

A little more info:

```
}catch(e){
        alert(e.description);
}
```

But other than that your implementation looks pretty good to me my friend.